# How to remove element in jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<div class="content">
    box 1 (Customer)
    <ol class='example mauDIDROP vertical'>
        <li>Valentino Rossi</li>
        <li>David Beckham</li>
        <li>Eden Hazard</li>
        <li>Lionel Messi</li>
        <li>Christiano Ronaldo</li>
        <li>Frank Lampard</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
        box 2 (Room Type)
        <br>
        <select id="room_type">
            <option value="1">Single Room</option>
            <option value="2">Double Room</option>
            <option value="3">Twin Room</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Add" style="margin-top: -10px;" id="add_room">

        <ol class="example areaDROP vertical" id="room_list">

            <li class="room_number msg1" id="room_remove11">Deluxe Room<div class="room-remove"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_room(11)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div><ol><li id="room_remove21">John Terry<div class="room-remove"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_room(21)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></li></ol></li>
            <li class="room_number msg1" id="room_remove12">Family Room<div class="room-remove"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_room(12)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div><ol><li id="room_remove22">Jose Mourinho<div class="room-remove"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_room(22)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></li></ol></li>
        </ol>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

My Javascript is like this :

```
    function delete_room(id){
        $('#room_remove'+id).remove();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("ol.mauDIDROP").sortable({
            group: '.example'
        });

        $("ol.areaDROP").sortable({
            group:  '.example',
        });

        var room_type_number = 5;
        $('#add_room').click(function(){
            var text = $("#room_type option:selected").html();
            var room_type_id = $.trim($('#room_type').val());       

            $('#room_list').append('<li class="room_number msg" id="room_remove'+(++room_type_number)+'" data-id="'+room_type_id+'" data-name="'+text+'">'+text+'<div class="room-remove"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove'+room_type_id+'" onclick="delete_room('+room_type_number+')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div><ol></ol></li>');

            $("ol.mauDIDROP").sortable({
                group: '.example'
            });

            $("ol.areaDROP").sortable({
                group:  '.example',    
            });              
        });
    });
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/4wnfnz6z/1/

When I click on the close icon, the selected element successfully deleted.

But what I want:
When I click on the close icon, the selected element removed and deleted customer element appears in box 1.

For example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eraM.jpg

When I click on the close icon(deluxe room), it will look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZOpG.jpg

How to keep deleted customer element in moving towards the box 1?

Any suggestion to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a bit your `delete_room` function so it would grab the names of customers from the room you are removing and then append them as `li`s to your left container:

```
function delete_room(id){
    var customers = '';
    $('#room_remove'+id).find('li').each( function() {
        customers += '<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
    });
    $('#room_remove'+id).remove();
    $('ol.example.mauDIDROP.vertical').append(customers);
}
```

Check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ngwn1vbr/)

Comment: I want to ask again. When click the button X, Whether it could use jquery sortable?
So when click the button X, then it will drag the customer element to box 1. So do not use the remove and append, but using drag & drop from jquery sortable

Comment: If you want to use drag&drop to do same thing as clicking X, you can add same functionality to `onDrop` event for the first box. I slightly rearranged previous code in this new revision: https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ngwn1vbr/1/

Comment: I am still confused. You try to see my case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868242/failed-get-json-data-in-jquery-sortable. I created a new question.

Comment: Check my answer there

Comment: Okey, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This approach have better performance, cause you are setting the find to a var and doing a loop instead of doind a loop with the find.

```
var child = $('#room_remove'+id).find('li');
if(child.length > 0){
    var li = "";
        child.each(function(){
            li += "<li>"+$(this).text()+"</li>";
        });
}

$(".mauDIDROP").append($(li));
```